# Flash messages displaying without color

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, railstutorial.org

I am trying to display a flash error message on invalid email/password input:

Snippet of the layout:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        user = User.find_by(email: params[:sessions][:email].downcase)
        if user && user.authenticate(params[:sessions][:password])
            # Sign the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
        else
            flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination"
            render 'new'
        end 
    end
end
```

But I get the above flash message as plain black text, when it should be red with stylized background.

Only `:success` displays the value(flash message) in green plain text, rest of the keys show plain text.

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: you should inspect the element and see if the class assigned is the same as you have for your css

Comment: Flash is just a hash stored within session, it has nothing to do how the messages are being displayed. Have a look in your layouts and style appropriate divs with css.

Comment: @BroiSatse I have checked the layout. There is nothing wrong with it. I even tried hard-coding it(class ="alert alert-error), it still showed plain text.

Comment: Do you have styles defined for those classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using bootstrap, try using `flash.now[:danger]` instead of `flash.now[:error]`